# Faster way of looping through each cell in a defined range - with offsets?

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the code I'm using

```
For Each x In strText
    x.Offset(, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=removeduplicates(RC[-1])"
    x.Offset(, 2).Value = x.Offset(, 3).Value
    x.Offset(, 3).ClearContents
Next x
```

The issue is that the range is 10,000 cells over 15 sheets so this takes ages. Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: What is `removeduplicates`? That sounds like a UDF. So you are writing code, to iterate through cells to put a formula in that calls VBA code that does <something> and sends it's value back to that cell, then you copy that value into another cell and remove the formula. That feels... pretty roundabout. How about reduce those three lines to just `x.Offset(,2)value = removeduplicates(x.offset(,-1).value)` (or whatever that's pointing to).

Comment: It is a UDF. It removes duplicates in a cell with strings separated by commas. It's roundabout because another macro outputs something into offset 2, then the formula removes the dupes, and then the final values are hardcoded into the original cell.

Comment: I guess my point is, just call it directly in your VBA. `Range("A1").Value = removeDuplicates(Range("B1").Value)` for instance would put the dedup'd values from B1 into A1 WITHOUT a formula. There is no reason to put it in a formula, wait for it to calculate and populate the cell, then copy the value and paste it into another cell and then delete the formula when you can just call the `removeduplicate()` function directly in VBA.

Comment: This doesn't really work here because another macro is outputting something into x.Offset(, 2) and that output has dupes. So to remove the dupes, I can't just do `.Offset(, 2).Value = RemoveDuplicates.Offset(, 2).Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
With strText
    .Offset(, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=removeduplicates(RC[-1])"
    .Offset(, 2).Value = .Offset(, 3).Value
    .Offset(, 3).ClearContents
End With
```